# restful-authentication 'Could not find generator authenticated'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, restful-authentication

I just installed the restful-authentication plugin on Rails 3, using:
rails plugin install git://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication.git

To generate the authentication files, the tutorial stated I should execute:

ruby script/generate authenticated user sessions --include-activation

(which in rails3 is):

rails g authenticated user sessions --include-activation

However, when I execute this line, I get the following error:
"Could not find generator authenticated."

..Does anyone have any pointers on how to get past this? I may have also messed up the 'rails g' command i specified.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nevermind. Found the solution on a forum. Tried using the git repository at http://github.com/satish/restful-authentication and it worked just fine. I think it's a mod of the original restful-authentication designed specifically for rails 3.

Answer (score 0):

you can use gem "rails3-restful-authentication" supported for rails 3.